# Finding the general solution of $u u_{xy} - u_x u_y = 0,$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the book of Berg, at page 4, at the end of the **introduction**, as an exercise, it is asked to find the general solution of

$$u u_{xy} - u_x u_y = 0,$$

however, considering the fact that the book haven't showed any method or anything at all, how can we find the general solution of this PDE ?

Comment: I don't know whether this leads anywhere, but that looks like the numerator of a differentiated fraction. Consider something like $\left(\frac{u_y}{u}\right)_x$.

Comment: What's you mean by general solution?

Comment: what is the reason for the down vote ?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne you can google it; it is terminology, not a vague statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**\begin{align}
uu_{xy}-u_xu_y &= 0 \\
\frac{u_xu_{xy}-u_xu_y}{u^2}&= 0 \\
\left(\frac{u_{y}}{u}\right)_x &= 0 \\
\frac{u_{y}}{u} &=h(y) \\
e^{-\int_0^y h(v) dv}u_{y} &=e^{-\int_0^y h(v) dv}h(y) u \\
 (e^{-\int_0^y h(v) dv}u)_y &= 0\\
 u &= g(x)e^{\int_0^y h(v) dv}=g(x)j(y)\\
\end{align}**

Answer (score -3):

Any solution of the form $u(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ is valid, since

$$ uu_{xy} - u_xu_y = fg\cdot \frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dy} - \frac{df}{dx}g\cdot f\frac{dg}{dy} = 0 $$

is always true